# RegEx to exclude number using PHP

Tags: php, regex, string

This question is a continuation of my previous question:

> [RegEx to exclude academic title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15307109/regex-to-exclude-academic-title)

I want split paragraph string into array of sentences using regular expression with character dot (.). And the next problem is about number.

Here is an example :

> In this year 2013. Hello Mr. Andre, your money is Rp 40.000.

Of course the correct output :

> Array ( [0] => In this year 2013 [1] => Hello Mr. Andre, your money is
>   Rp 40.000 )

The title problem (Mr.) is already solved from my question before. I've tried with adding regex of number but still don't work.

My not worked code :

```
$titles_number=array('(^[0-9]*)','(?<!Mr)', '(?<!Mrs)', '(?<!Ms)');
$sentences=preg_split('/('.implode('',$titles_number).')\./',$text);
print_r($sentences);
```

Can I do this with one blow (one regex to get rid two problem)? Tell me if I can't do it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using the building blocks `(?<!\d)` `(?!\d)` for negative lookahead and look behind for digits?

Comment: Although I don't have an answer for you, the site www.regexpal.com is a great way to test regular expressions. It's JavaScript-based, so it updates in real-time. I use it a lot.

Comment: Thanks for comment, still trying. http://regex101.com/ is worth to try too :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be easier to accomplish with `preg_match_all()`:

```
preg_match_all(
    '/[^\s.][^.]*(?:\.(?:(?<=Prof\.|Dr\.|Mr\.|Mrs\.|Ms\.)|(?=\d))[^.]*)*\./',
    $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
print_r($result[0]);
```

explanation:

- `[^\s.]` matches the next non-whitespace character (i.e., skip over any whitespace between sentences)
- `[^.]*` gobbles up any non-dot characters
- `\.` matches a dot IF...
- `(?<=Prof\.|Dr\.|Mr\.|Mrs\.|Ms\.)` ...it's part of an honorific...
- `(?=\d)` ...or part of a number

notes:

1. `(?<=Prof\.|Dr\.|Mr\.|Mrs\.|Ms\.)` is legal because the alternation is at the top level. That is, it acts like several discrete lookbehinds, each with a fixed length.  That's why I had to repeat the `\.` in every branch instead of using `(?<=(?:Prof|Dr|Mr|Mrs|Ms)\.)`.
2. `\.(?=\d)` seems to be sufficient for identifying a dot that's part of a number.  If you really have to check for digits before and after the dot, you can use `(?=(?<=\d\.)\d)` instead.
3. If this is for anything more serious than a homework problem, you should discard regexes and look for a natural-language processing library.  Crude as all this is, it's very close to the limit of what you can do with regexes.

Comment: Wow, this is complete answer and get rid typo problem too, thanks master.. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the number problem (and probably others) if you notice that each dot at the  end of a sentence is followed by a space/tab/newline or by the end of the string:

```
$titles=array('(?<!Mr)', '(?<!Mrs)', '(?<!Ms)');
$sentences=preg_split('/('.implode('',$titles).')\.(?=\s|$)/',$text);
print_r($sentences);
```

Comment: Wow, nice idea. But this is not work when there's typo problem like this : "In this year 2013.Hello Mr. Andre, your money is Rp 40.000." Overall thank you for answer :D